# Detailed ServiceDescription / Proxy from WSDL

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, proxy-classes, dynamic-proxy

I am using the classes ServiceDescription / ServiceDescriptionImporter to dynamically call web services. I'd like to dig a bit deeper into the WSDL description and get

1) Parameter info for each of the web methods

2) The actual types / composition each parameters of all the web methods (ie if a WebMethod takes some complex type as a parameter, I need to know the primitive / other types it is composed of as well, if possible)

Here is the code I have for the dynamical call:

```
    public static object CallWebService(string webServiceAsmx, string serviceName, string methodName, object[] args = null)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        Stream stream = client.OpenRead(webServiceAsmx + "?wsdl");
        ServiceDescription description = ServiceDescription.Read(stream);
        ServiceDescriptionImporter importer = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();

        importer.ProtocolName = "Soap12";
        importer.AddServiceDescription(description, null, null);
        importer.Style = ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client;
        importer.CodeGenerationOptions = CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;
```

I have been able to get as far as finding some basic info such as the method names, parameter info, but I need deeper analysis. For example I need access to essentially all the information that Wsdl.exe produces in proxy classes but I dont want to have to run Wsdl.exe, just discover the information dynamically. For every method I need to know what its return type is composed of, what its parameters are composed of, etc. I know its in the WSDL just not sure how to programmatically extract it. Here are some of the classes Ive been exploring:

```
ServiceDescription.Description 
ServiceDescription.Messages
ServiceDescription.Types
```

It seems that alot of them come up empty though?

Thanks in advance.

**EDITS**

I got a little further, this is the xml schema (WSDL) I am trying to traverse:

```
- <s:complexType name="Session">
- <s:complexContent mixed="false">
- <s:extension base="tns:EntityObject">
 - <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="s:string" /> 
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Host" type="s:string" /> 
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SessionType" type="s:string" /> 
    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LoginTime" type="s:dateTime" /> 
    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LogoutTime" type="s:dateTime" /> 
   </s:sequence>
  </s:extension>
 </s:complexContent>
   </s:complexType>
```

And this is the code to traverse:

```
 foreach (System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaComplexType item in xmlSchema.SchemaTypes.Values)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaParticle particle = item.Particle;
                System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSequence sequence = particle as System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSequence;

                if (sequence != null)
                {
                    foreach (System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaElement childElement in sequence.Items)
                    {
                        string name = childElement.Name;
                        string type = childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name;

                        Console.WriteLine(name + " " + type); 
                    }
                }
            }
```

This gets me a little further, but not as far as getting the complexContent of the ComplexType. Produces the following output in the console:

Session Session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has a similar question, here is how I did it:

```
foreach (System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaComplexType item in xmlSchema.SchemaTypes.Values)
        {
            ComplexType cType = new ComplexType(item.Name);

            System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaContentModel model = item.ContentModel;
            System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaComplexContent complex = model as System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaComplexContent;

            if (complex != null)
            {
                System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaComplexContentExtension extension = complex.Content as System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaComplexContentExtension;
                System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaParticle particle = extension.Particle;
                System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSequence sequence = particle as System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSequence;

                if (sequence != null)
                {
                    List<SimpleType> primitives = new List<SimpleType>(); 

                    foreach (System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaElement childElement in sequence.Items)
                    {
                        string name = childElement.Name;
                        string type = childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name;
                        cType.Primitives.Add(new SimpleType(name, type));
                    }

                    if (cType.Name == parameter.Type || "ArrayOf" + cType.Name == parameter.Type)
                    {
                        descriptions.Add(new ComplexParameter(cType, item.Name));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sean, Seems to be interesting code. Appreciate if you can share the entire code if you don't mind. I was trying to implement the same but getting lot of difficulties. In above code, Not sure, what is parameter, description and ComplexParameter. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This looks pretty similar to what you you did [WebServiceInfo](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2006/06/simple-wsdl-object.html)  It returns custom objects with the info. (if I am understanding your question and the blog well enough)