# Creating a Web Service consumer from a WSDL with nested complex types

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I am trying to create a web service consumer, given a WSDL of a service that is already up and running. The challenge is, doing the whole thing dynamically, in runtime. I am working with C#. To sum up, I have to do the following:

1. I have an application that will be given as input the WSDL file (url). **done**
2. The application will drill down the WSDL file, recognizing the operations, messages and the types used. (**point that I'm having trouble with**)
3. It will create the code needed to invoke the Web Service, compile it and load it through reflection. **done**
4. Have everything ready for invocation, including creating and sending the necessary parameters to the remote method. Then it'll handle the response properly. **done**

I am having some issues with #2, which is parsing and drilling down in the WSDL file. In specific: extracting complex types that appear to be "nested".

I've read some very useful resources about extracting complex types:

[Parse Complex WSDL Parameter Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452724/parse-complex-wsdl-parameter-information)

[Detailed ServiceDescription / Proxy from WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264066/detailed-servicedescription-proxy-from-wsdl)

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2006/06/simple-wsdl-object.html

However, I am a bit puzzled with an example WSDL that I have received for testing:

```
<definitions name='MyWSService' targetNamespace='http://some.url.com/' xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' xmlns:tns='http://some.url.com/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
 <types>
  <xs:schema attributeFormDefault='qualified' elementFormDefault='qualified' targetNamespace='http://some.url.com/' version='1.0' xmlns:tns='http://some.url.com/' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
   <xs:element name='dsSendOperationName' type='tns:systemSendOperationName'/>
   <xs:element name='dsSendOperationNameResponse' type='tns:systemSendOperationNameResponse'/>
   <xs:complexType name='systemSendOperationName'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='systemOperationName' type='tns:systemOperationName'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='systemOperationName'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='param1' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='param2' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='param3' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='param4' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='param5' type='xs:string'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='systemSendOperationNameResponse'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='return' type='xs:string'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:schema>
 </types>
 <message name='SystemOperationNameWS_dsSendOperationName'>
  <part element='tns:dsSendOperationName' name='dsSendOperationName'></part>
 </message>
 <message name='SystemOperationNameWS_dsSendOperationNameResponse'>
  <part element='tns:dsSendOperationNameResponse' name='dsSendOperationNameResponse'></part>
 </message>
 <portType name='SystemOperationNameWS'>
  <operation name='dsSendOperationName' parameterOrder='dsSendOperationName'>
   <input message='tns:SystemOperationNameWS_dsSendOperationName'></input>
   <output message='tns:SystemOperationNameWS_dsSendOperationNameResponse'></output>
  </operation>
 </portType>
 <binding name='SystemOperationNameWSBinding' type='tns:SystemOperationNameWS'>
  <soap:binding style='document' transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>
  <operation name='dsSendOperationName'>
   <soap:operation soapAction=''/>
   <input>
    <soap:body use='literal'/>
   </input>
   <output>
    <soap:body use='literal'/>
   </output>
  </operation>
 </binding>
 <service name='SystemOperationNameWSService'>
  <port binding='tns:SystemOperationNameWSBinding' name='SystemOperationNameWSPort'>
   <soap:address location='http://a.url.here.com'/>
  </port>
 </service>
</definitions>
```

Look how the root elements (as defined in the messages' section) are referring to a complex type, which has an element that is later on declared as a complex type, that finally has a sequence of elements with standard XSD types.

Programatically, I am able to drill down to the very last element of that "chain". However, I am confused about the type of the actual message being sent to the web service. Is it:

1. A systemSendOperationName that wraps a systemOperationName, that contains 5 strings?
   or
2. A systemOperationName object that contains 5 strings?

And overall, is that sort of nested types normal? I haven't found a similar example so far.

EDIT:

Made some points of my initial post more clear to avoid any confusions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating proxy using wsdl programmatically and wsdl parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600761/creating-proxy-using-wsdl-programmatically-and-wsdl-parsing)

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am having a more specific problem parsing complex types as displayed in the example wsdl, and not generating a proxy class. The question you linked is asking for everything about proxy class generation, while I am asking something more specific. I have written the whole story about the WS Consumer to avoid the "XY Problem" as much as possible.

Comment: nantito, that answer does exactly what you described in `3` and `4` (*"It will create the code needed to invoke the Web Service"* This is the **proxy** asked in this question)

Comment: Yes, you're right. However, I am writing later on that the points 3 and 4 can be ignored (consider them as already done). Perhaps I should have made it more clear in my post. I am having an issue with #2 and with the very specific case of nested complex types as shown in the example wsdl.

Comment: Edited slightly the initial post to make it more clear. Thanks I4V!